# Android Wi-Fi lock: How long should the program wait after acquiring a wifi lock?

Tags: android, locking, wifi

Given an application that sends a network request every 15 minutes and a user that would like the Wi-Fi awoken from sleep when necessary in order to save data, how long should the application wait before sending the request?

Obtaining a wifi lock won't instantly result in a connected status, so what does android guidelines suggest for such delay?  I can't wait for my "connected receiver" either because there's always the possibility that the device can't connect to any network even though the wifi lock is acquired (in the case where there is not wifi present).  Is there a standard for this?  Instead of thread.sleep, I plan on using a handler/runnable to postdelay.  Currently, I am just waiting 15 seconds.  Thanks in advance.